# Консольное приложение Net Core использует библиотеку классов Net Standart?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Консольное приложение Net Core использует библиотеку классов Net Standart?

Если я создам консольное приложение Net Core и в свойствах изменю на библиотеку, то оно превратится в Библиотеку классов Net Standart?

Будут какие-то отличия?

Comment: ".NET Standard представляет собой официальную спецификацию интерфейсов API .NET, которые должны быть доступны во всех средах выполнения .NET." - взято https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/library. Т.О. Standard это не библиотека, не платформа, и не код. Standard - это набор "правил" для создания API. Изходя из этого ничего для вашего проекта не изменится. Но т.к Core соответствует Standard 1.0 его можно изпользовать в других средах поддерживающий тот же стандарт. (например в .Net) Спецификация - https://github.com/dotnet/standard